# rsync deleting files despite --dry-run

Tags: ssh, rsync, delete-file, authorized-keys, dry-run

When I run rsync with --delete and --dry-run specified, deleted local files are actually deleted on the remote. Command output includes (DRY RUN) at the end, but the remote files are deleted.
Command I'm running:

```
rsync \
    -azv --dry-run --delete \
    -e "ssh -l backup -i /home/user/.ssh/id_backup" \
    --include-from='/home/user/.rsync-include.txt' \
    --exclude-from='/home/user/.rsync-exclude.txt' \
    /home/user backup:storage/backups/home
```

Sample output:

```
sending incremental file list
deleting user/zxcv
deleting user/asdf
user/

sent 7,091 bytes  received 62 bytes  4,768.67 bytes/sec
total size is 97,628,177  speedup is 13,648.56 (DRY RUN)
```

(note the `(DRY RUN)` at the end)

But on the remote server, the files that were there are deleted. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the result of specifying a `command="[rsync command]"` in ssh's authorized_keys file on the remote machine. That command didn't include the --dry-run option.  Changing options on the local machine doesn't work properly when the command is restricted by the `command=` ssh option on the remote machine.